# how do I install an extension in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

I downloaded master .zip from the civi website, and it is in my download box. How do I get it to a folder in my website to put the zip into my program

Comment: Are you asking about installing CiviCRM plugin in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I went to civi and downloaded "wordpress-civicrm-master"  to my computer. you might have guessed I am new to civi. When I go to manage extensions, in civi administrator, then to add new, this this extension is not there. How do I get it there so I can add it to civi

Answer (score 2):

If you have CiviCRM installed on your WordPress installation as a plugin and you are inside CiviCRM trying to install a CiviCRM Extension.  This is what I do to had an extension that is not automatically available with CiviCRM Extension manager.  I go to my server manager CPanel and use the file manager to upload the extension zip file.  I place the extension zip file in to the folder;  public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions. Extract the zip file and the new CiviCRM extension will become available to install within the CiviCRM Extension Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The new wordpress directories is:
public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext
Upload the zip files here and then extract them into the folder. you then have to go to the extension page and click refresh for them to show and to be able to install.